# How to make sure messages from an email address never get sent to spam?

Tags: gmail, spam-prevention

In Gmail, how can I make sure email from a company email address never gets sent to spam? A company that I want to receive emails from always gets put into spam and even though I set their email address as a contact all of their messages still get sent to spam. How can I makes this stop?

Comment: Which email you are using - Gmail, Yahoo! or any other?

Comment: I am using Gmail

Answer (score 2):

Create a filter and make sure you select **Never send it to Spam** from the options list.

[image]